# Vue 3 composition API Router Params with Navigation Auth Guard

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am having a small problem where I don't know what to do. I tried so many diffrent solutions but nothing worked.

My Problem:

I got a navigation Guard:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, useRoute } from "vue-router";
import { isAuthenticated } from "../service/axios-auth";
import ChangePasswordView from "../views/ChangePasswordView.vue";
import LoginView from "../views/LoginView.vue";
import HomeView from "../views/HomeView.vue";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: HomeView,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/password-reset/Token/:Token",
      name: "password-reset",
      component: ChangePasswordView,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: false,
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: LoginView,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: false,
      }
    }
  ],
});

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.params.Token != null) {
    next({ name:"password-reset", params: { Token: to.fullPath }})
  } else if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!(await isAuthenticated())) {
      next('/login');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
     next();
  }
})

export default router;
```

and I want to call an external Link (http://localhost:5173/password-reset/Token/A1EB34589AD1CCEE77C79BDDC5A3187DF51D3368F08B49DA833AB902CBC812A513A11C111455DB8FB2C0824E5401096F31CFB6D1CEDABCCB549BF5C5D3B1747F)
but as soon as I open this link nothing happens and the website is loading infinitely.

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am basicly stupid... Inside my password-reset View I have a onMount function that checks if I am logged in. This function pushes the router to the home View. That's why I can't access the password-reset site :)

Answer (score 2):

What does this block mean?

```js
if (to.params.Token != null) {
    next({ name:"password-reset", params: { Token: to.fullPath }})
}
```

if the route has a `Token` param then redirect it to `password-reset`. It's a loop. because the `password-reset` route has the `Token` param, it will get back to it over & over.
I don't know precisely what you want to do with this check. It does nothing, other than looping around.
I would like to understand more about your implementation, so I can assist you.

Also, you can access the `meta` field of the route directly from the `to` parameter. [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html)

```js
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth === true && !(await isAuthenticated())) {
      next('/login');
      return;
  }
  next();
})
```

Comment: currently I want to access the view password-reset with a parameter. But as soon as I request the website with the param (http://localhost:5173/password-reset/Token/{Token}) I will be redirected to the login screen and not to the requested password-reset view

Comment: I understand that if the link has a token, it will be redirected to `Login` view. Although it doesn't make any sense. the `reset-password` view is what should handle this action. and if there is no token, then redirect him to `Login`.
However, to do this, you have to redirect to `/login`:
```if (to.params.Token != null) next('/login');```

Comment: @c3dr1c-4k;
You already have authentication checker in `router.beforeEach`. you don't need to put it in the view.
Also, the `reset-password` view should not be accessible for authenticated users, only for `guest` users.